# SNMP operations on MIB

Tags: monitoring, snmp, net-snmp, network-monitoring, snmpd

Hello i am creating a MIB and i have a table with attributes of files. I have name, file type. etc... and a DateAndTime object to represent the time at which the file was created.
In order to delete elements of said table one column has to be of the RowStatus type.

Now my question is, if i wanted to get all files that were created in the last 12 hours what command sequence would the snmp agent use to select that?
To my knowledge it is not possible to select data within a timeframe attribute inside a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is no way to select data with timestamps in SNMP as you would do in a sql query.

In a table you have to read all the data and, if needed just select he lines that start within the timeframe you are looking for.